# Optimal installation of tensorflow with M1 Mac native Anaconda 2022.05

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, apple-m1, mini-forge

Now that Anaconda is natively supporting M1 Macs with their 2022.05 release, I was wondering what the best way to install tensorflow on these machines is.

> https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1

```
conda create -n anaconda_mac_2 tensorflow
```

as suggested on https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/ fails on my machine.

I can successfully install a working version of tensorflow with conda-forge like so

```
conda install conda-forge::tensorflow
```

however this is not utilsing the GPUs as with previous versions of anaconda:

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "Not Available")
```

> GPU is Not Available

is it still best to make use of the M1 GPU architecture with the tensorflow-metal releases and run a separate version through miniforge that supports aarch64?

Would be grateful if anyone has already some experience or even done some testing, Cheers.

Comment: You can use a community-supported Anaconda package to install Tensorflow, read the [Anaconda TensorFlow guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks four your response TFer - as far as I can see this is describing CPU-only installs for macOS (which I am assuming are not aarch64 native and does not optimally exploit the new GPU architecture - but maybe I'm wrong ?).

Comment: Does this help https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/#cuda-versions. Thanks!

Comment: thanks TFer - I have tested this and edited my question accordingly. Let me know if I missed anything... Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it has changed any: if you want Apple GPU support, you still go through the **apple** channel for `tensorflow-deps` and install `tensorflow-metal` with Pip. https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Comment: thanks, I'm getting the same impression after trying this yesterday. Cheers